# How to make a role for a guild in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried doing this

```
const discord = require("discord.js")
const Event = require("../Structures/Events")

module.exports = new Event("guildCreate", (message, client) =>{

    Discord.guild.roles.edit(guild.id, {
        hoist: false,
        mentionable: false,
        permissions: []
    })

    Discord.guild.roles.create({ ALL THE ROLE DATA })
})
```

But got this error:

> Discord.guild.roles.create({
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my event handler

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js")

const Client = require ("./Client.js")

/**
 * 
 * @param {Client} client 
 * @param  {Discord.ClientEvents[K]} eventArgs 
 */
function runFunction(client, ...eventArgs){}
/**
 * @template {key of Discord.ClientEvents} K
 */
class Event {
    /**
     * 
     * @param {K} event 
     * @param {runFunction<K>} runFunction 
     */
    constructor(event, runFunction){
        this.event = event
        this.run = runFunction
    }
}

module.exports = Event
```

Comment: Please view [The Guide](https://discordjs.guide/), you've got alot of things wrong.

Comment: can you tell me what have i done wrong @Elitezen

Comment: 1) Your Discord module is defined as `discord` not `Discord`. 2) Use event listeners from your client object, you shouldn't have to be creating new `Event` instances. 3) You should be using `message` to access `message.guild` which will return the guild object. View the guide, all of this is covered clearly. 4) `guildCreate` does not emit a message actually

Comment: 1) Was a typo. 2) I have tried stuff with the event listeners before and it works so there is no problem with it. 3) using message to access the guild object will simply not work here because the event is guildCreate and not when someone sends a message so using message.guild instead will just give an error that message is not defined. And I have read the docs obviously to know most of the stuff I just wanted to know whats causing this error and how I can fix it 4) guildCreate is an event @Elitezen

Comment: A typo is enough to cause an error in programming. And yes `guildCreate` is an event but as I stated it *does not emit a message...*, It emits a Guild as expected and as seen [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate)

Comment: tbh I dont want a message I do want the guild

Comment: You don't get to choose what the event's parameters are, they are emitted internally by the API and library, the problem is with how you name them and believe they represent something else

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the code would look based off the [Discord.JS Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Using your client's event listeners as it's standard. `guildCreate` does not emit a message or a client, but rather the new guild itself (as expected)

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
   guild.roles.edit(guild.id, {
      hoist: false,
      mentionable: false,
      permissions: []
   });

   guild.roles.create(...);
});
```

Comment: gives the error that guild is not defined

Comment: The event *will* emit a guild object, can you show your code?

Comment: fixed the problem, the problem was }) at the wrong place